# Modify file create time in windows using only C

Tags: c, windows, file

I moving files from one folder to another in windows and want to save the original file date stamps to the new file. I can successfully copy access date and modification date using <utime.h> and <sys/stat.h>
I want to also copy the create date where applicable. I see that C++ has the GetFileTime function (fileapi.h) to do this and other languages can do this. Can it be done purely in C and if so how?

Comment: The headers you mention aren't standard C headers but POSIX headers. You're fine with using POSIX on Windows? Also, do you face compilation issues if you use `fileapi.h`?

Comment: @Zoso: `fileapi.h` isn't a POSIX header, it's a Win32 header, and one uses `#include <windows.h>` and never actually cares which specific header the prototype is in.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletime

Comment: @BenVoigt I was referring to `<utime.h>` and `<sys/stat.h>` as the POSIX headers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works on my Window 10 system. Thank you for your help.

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    HANDLE hFile1, hFile2;
    FILETIME ftCreate1, ftAccess1, ftWrite1, ftCreate2, ftAccess2, ftWrite2;
    SYSTEMTIME st, stUTC, stLocal;

    // file names, change accordingly
    char fname1[ ] = "C:\\PathToFile\\testfile01.txt";
    char fname2[ ] = "C:\\PathToFile\\testfile02.txt";

    BOOL bRet = FALSE;
    
    //OPEN FILES
    // open first file
    hFile1 = CreateFile(
                fname1,                 // file to open
                GENERIC_READ,           // open for reading
                FILE_SHARE_READ,        // share for reading
                NULL,                   // default security
                OPEN_EXISTING,          // existing file only
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  // normal file
                NULL                    // no attribute template
            );
    // open second file
    hFile2 = CreateFile(
                fname2,                 // file to open
                GENERIC_WRITE,          // open for writing 
                FILE_SHARE_READ,        
                NULL,                   
                OPEN_EXISTING,          
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,  
                NULL                    
            );                  

    // check file handles have opened successfully
    if(hFile1 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("Could not open %s file, error %d\n", fname1, GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    if(hFile2 == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE){
        printf("Could not open %s file, error %d\n", fname2, GetLastError());
        return 1;
    }
    
    // GET FILE TIMES 
    // retrieve the file times from the first file.
    if(!GetFileTime(hFile1, &ftCreate1, &ftAccess1, &ftWrite1)){
        printf("GetFileTime Failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // SYSTEM TIME
    // get system time and assign to variable for saving current time - if required
    GetSystemTime(&st);                                     // gets current time
    SystemTimeToFileTime(&st, &ftAccess2);                  // converts to file time 
    
    // SET TIME ON FILE!!!
    // set file times for second file, NULL to keep existing timestamp
    if(SetFileTime(hFile2, &ftCreate1, &ftAccess2, NULL)){
        printf("SetFileTime Successful!\n");
    }else{
        printf("SetFileTime Failed!\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // PRINT
    // convert filetime to readable date format for printing to stdout
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftCreate1, &stUTC);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC, &stLocal);
    printf("Created: %02d/%02d/%d %02d:%02d\n", stLocal.wDay, stLocal.wMonth, stLocal.wYear, stLocal.wHour, stLocal.wMinute);   

    
    // close the file handles
    CloseHandle(hFile1);
    CloseHandle(hFile2);
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 3):

The Windows API is designed to be called from C.  Write

```
#include <windows.h>
```

in a C program and the compiler will accept usage of `GetFileTime` and `SetFileTime`.  You'll then need to link with the `kernel32.lib` import library, which may already be in your library list by default.

C++ actually has to use `extern "C"` to call these functions because they aren't C++ functions at all (The header files do this automatically, based on `#if __cplusplus` so you don't have to worry about it.  The header files also automatically mark these declarations with the `stdcall` calling convention on x86, you don't have to worry about that either unless you form a function pointer.)